# Add step installer electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How to add an installation step to the application? In order for the installation to read the terms of use.

I use - [Electron Installer](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer#handling-squirrel-events)

There is an event: --squirrel-install

What to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you actually shouldn't use a Squirrel events to handle this, as documentation stated:

> Squirrel will spawn your app with command line flags on first run, updates, and uninstalls. it is very important that your app handle these events as early as possible, and quit immediately after handling them. 
>   Squirrel will give your app a short amount of time (~15sec) to apply these operations and quit.

Which isn't suitable for showing terms of use so I'd suggest having a boolean flag in the filesystem indicating if the user has accepted terms of use. Moreover, by storing a flag in filesystem you can avoid situations when your applications were restarted without reading terms of use.

**UPDATE:** You might want to use [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) instead, it supports license dialog for [macOS](https://www.electron.build/configuration/dmg#dmg-license) and [Windows](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis).

Comment: Thanks, you can give a link to an example of using the installation steps. Could not find.

Comment: Here is [quick setup guide](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#quick-setup-guide) and [boilerplate project](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate) that uses electron-builder